# Regex to match Number of 1-3 Digits After a Known String in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string, numbers

I need to match the numbers in the following strings. It is possible they may be part of longer strings with other numbers in them, so I specifically want to match **the number(s) occuring directly after the space which follows the text 'Error Code'**:

```
Error Code 0  # Match = 0
Error Code 45 # Match = 45
Error Code 190 # Match = 190
```

Also possible:

```
Some Words 12 Error Code 67 Some Words 77 # Match = 67
```

I'm using `someString.match(regEx)[0]` but I can't get the regex right.

Comment: Which language are you using? And what is the regEx you are trying?

Answer (score 18):

```
/(?:Error Code )[0-9]+/
```

This uses a non-capturing group (not available in all regex implementations.)  It will say, hey the String better have this phrase, but I don't want this phrase to be part of my match, just the numbers that follow.

If you only want between 1 and three digits matched:

```
/(?:Error Code )[0-9]{1,3}/
```

With Ruby you should run into very few limitations with your regex.  Aside from conditionals, there isn't very much Ruby's regex cannot do.

Comment: +1 - Rather than `[0-9]` I'd do `\d`, otherwise this should work fine. I tweaked it to show the regex delimiters -- some OPs can't figure out those are needed too.

Comment: Thanks. But this seems to include the string in the match: `s = 'This is an Error Code 45 and some 19s'`
`puts s.match(/(?:Error Code )[0-9]{1,3}/)[0]` gives a match of 'Error Code 45'

Comment: When I answer many regex questions online, I tend to use 0-9 etc. as they are immediately obvious to the OPs.  \d makes people need to know that it indicates the same thing.  (Also, in small regex like this, I prefer to use 0-9 as it is more readable to me.)

Comment: Hmm, I am not familiar enough with Ruby (read: not at all) to know why it wouldn't recognize the non-capturing group notation...

Answer (score 9):

Given the string "Error Code 190", this will return "190" and not "Error Code" like the other regex example provided here.

```
(?<=Error Code.*)[0-9]
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the following regex:

```
/Error\sCode\s\d{1,3}/
```

Or, with named groups:

```
/Error\sCode\s(?<error_code>\d{1,3})/
```

The last one will capture the error code, the number, under a named group. Note that `\s` matchs whitespaces but it's unnecessary unless the x flag is specified. You can access match captures like this:

```
str = "Error Code 0\nError Code 45\nError Code 190"
error_codes = str.lines.map{|l|l.match(regex)[:error_code]}
#=> ["0", "45", "190"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regexp:
Only digits, count from 1 to 3:

```
regexp = "^\\d{1,3}$"
```